# Cakephp 3 - force logout on session timeout

Tags: session, authentication, cakephp, logout

I'm struggling with the auth component.
My authentication is managed inside a plugin.
In the plugin's AppController.php I have set up this :

```
    $this->loadComponent('Auth', [
                                   'authenticate'      => [ 'Form' => [ 'userModel' => 'BasUsers' ] ],
                                   'loginAction'       => [ 'controller' => 'BasUsers', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => 'Basic' ],            
                                   'userModel'         => 'BasUsers',
                                   'loginRedirect'     => '/pages/home',
                                   'logoutRedirect'    => [ 'controller' => 'BasUsers', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => 'Basic' ],
                                   'unauthorizedRedirect' => [ 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'not-authorized' ],
                                   'authError'         => false,
                                   'authorize' => ['Controller'],
                                ]
                         );
```

I cannot manage to force a logout ( redirect to the login page ) when the session expires.

When the session ends, trying $this->request->session()->read( 'Auth.User.bas_users_role_id' ) returns null, but the controller / action is executed.

What am I missing ?
Thanks.

Comment: check for auth allow function...you may you are allowing all the actions in controller. like $this->Auth->allow(); .restricting/removing it may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Maybe your [browser retain your credential](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/controllers/components/authentication.html#logging-users-out)

2 - In your Appcontroler try to use isAuthorized function

```
public function isAuthorized($user)
{
if(is_null($this->request->session()->read( 'Auth.User.bas_users_role_id' )  ) :
    return $this->redirect(
        [ 'controller' => 'BasUsers', 'action' => 'login', 'plugin' => 'Basic' ]
    );
else: 
// your code
endif;
}
```

Comment: I've been testing and I found out that it is needed to load the Auth component in the initialize method of every plugin used in the application in order to make it aware of who is going to do the authentication ( in this case the Basic plugin ).  I'm not sure if this is the correct approach but it works.